# prob function in of rolldie but I dont know how to wirte excatly, see in question b

Tags: r

preconditions: the "prob" package and a seirous packages it requires has been installed

a)  Consider the experiment of rolling three dice. Using R, show how would you use a user-defined function to define a random variable that is the mean of the three rolls rounded to the nearest integer.

```
> rollthree <- rolldie(3, makespace = TRUE)
> rollthree$mean = as.integer((rollthree$X1 + rollthree$X2 + rollthree$X3)/3)
> rollthree
    X1 X2 X3      probs mean
1    1  1  1 0.00462963    1
2    2  1  1 0.00462963    1
... ...
```

b)  Using the above result, what is the probability that the random variable equals 3? What is the probability that the random variable takes a value of at most 3? What is the probability that the random variable takes on a value of at least 3? Use the Prob function as shown in the code samples.

```
> equal3 <- subset(rollthree$mean, rank == 3)
```

````
Error in rank == 3 : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that subset can't operate on rank, one solution to this would be to have `equal3 <- subset(rollthree, mean == 3)` which woud store all of the rows wher we have a mean of 3. Then we can sum the probabilities or multiply our probability for a single roll by the length of the array.

Using your code as a base I have produced the following code.

```r
library(prob)

# Part a

rollthree <- rolldie(3, makespace = T)
rollthree$mean = as.integer((rollthree$X1 + rollthree$X2 + rollthree$X3)/ 3)

# Part b

print("Probability mean is 3:")
# Note here we sum the probablities from the events we want to occur
# Additionally we have done this all in one line by taking only the mean column from the subset
sum(subset(rollthree, mean == 3)$prob)

print("Probability mean is less than or equal to 3:")
sum(subset(rollthree, mean <= 3)$prob)

print("Probability mean is greater than or equal to 3:")
sum(subset(rollthree, mean >= 3)$prob)

#> [1] "Probability mean is 3:"
#> [1] 0.3657407

#> [1] "Probability mean is less than or equal to 3:"
#> [1] 0.625

#> [1] "Probability mean is greater than or equal to 3:"
#> [1] 0.7407407
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

An alternate approach for a) is written below:

```r
library(prob)

# part a

#function to roll and calculate the means for some number of dice
roll_x_mean_int <- function(x) {
  # Check the input value is an integer
  if(typeof(x) != "integer"){
    stop("Input value is not an integer")
  }
  # Check the input value is positive
  if(x < 1){
    stop("Input integer is not positive")
  }
  # Roll the die
  vals <- rolldie(x, makespace = T)
  # Calculate the sum of each row (excluding the value of the probability)
  vals$mean <- as.integer(rowSums(vals[1:x]/x))
  return(vals)
}

# Call the fucntion with 3 dice (note the L makes the value an integer)
rollthree <- roll_x_mean_int(3L)

# part b

# Called this section as one block
{
  print("Probability mean is 3:")
  print(sum(subset(rollthree, mean == 3)$prob))

  print("Probability mean is less than or equal to 3:")
  print(sum(subset(rollthree, mean <= 3)$prob))

  print("Probability mean is greater than or equal to 3:")
  print(sum(subset(rollthree, mean >= 3)$prob))
}
#> [1] "Probability mean is 3:"
#> [1] 0.3657407

#> [1] "Probability mean is less than or equal to 3:"
#> [1] 0.625

#> [1] "Probability mean is greater than or equal to 3:"
#> [1] 0.7407407
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>